# Code Golf UserScript to help in navigating the site [v0.37 now available]

Tags: discussion

### Current version:

The current version of the script is **0.37**.

---

I was inspired by [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167/line-break-formats-and-character-numbers) Meta post to write a UserScript that would automatically tally up the size of code blocks and display the count underneath.

A couple weeks later and I now have a giant UserScript that is over 32kb in size :)

### Well, how can I install it?

I'm glad you asked! Since this is a UserScript, a few browsers allow you to install it by simply clicking on the link below and downloading it.

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/codegolf/count_it.user.js

*I have tested the script on [Chrome (needs this workaround)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/583/95), Firefox (with GreaseMonkey), and Opera. It is reported to work on Safari using GreaseKit.*

### What does it do exactly?

This list seems to grow every day, but here is a (somewhat) exhaustive list:

- Analysis and display of *exact* character count of each code entry (with syntax highlighting):

  [image]

  *Note: you can even directly run some entries by clicking the '[Run]' link*
- Summary of entries for a particular question, including the current winner(s) for shortest code:

  [image]
- The ability to sort the answers on the page by the size of their code:

  [image]
- An evolving options menu for changing the settings for the script:

  [image]
- An experimental theme that can be injected onto the pages of the site:

  [image]

### What about updates?

Yes, this humble UserScript is now capable of updating itself. Every 24 hours, it checks to see if there is a new version available. If so, it will prompt you to download it. You will have the option of choosing not to install the update if you don't want to.

**Version History:**

- **0.37** fixed support for some languages, deleted answers no longer count
- **0.36** added syntax highlighting
- **0.35** added warning for >30 answers, added live preview
- **0.34** added ability to run certain code entries
- **0.33** added menu item for reporting problems with the current page
- **0.32** made enhancements to theme, added more settings, changed about box
- **0.31** added options to dialog, added experimental theme
- **0.30** more reorganization, added smooth scrolling
- **0.29** complete reorganization of code, added HTML5 local storage support
- **0.28** added settings menu to top of page, fixed non-unique update URL problem
- **0.27** fixed script grabbing extra text for username field, added support for `<h3>` elements
- **0.26** added support for code-bowling posts
- **0.25** script now only runs on questions with code-golf tag
- **0.24** added DC programming language, fixed tab showing up on wrong pages
- **0.23** added special handler for C++ code entries
- **0.22** fixed links with new sort order, fixed multiple tied winners problem
- **0.21** added new sorting option
- **0.20** support for Firefox and Opera added, fixed jQuery include bug
- **0.19** added username, added more languages
- **0.18** added language to header, reorganized language code
- **0.17** fixed jQuery load bug, detects HQ9+ entries, fixed off-by-one count errors
- **0.16** fixed comment bug, moved header block, only first code block qualifies
- **0.15** added auto-update support

Comment: Ideas for improvement are welcome!

Comment: Clever. Alas it doesn't know the difference between when I inserted a line break because this was a c pre-processor line, when I inserted an unnecessary line break to so the code would fit in display and when I inserted a line break so the code would fit in the display *but in lieu of a space*.

Comment: @dmckee: Can you give me a link to that post? I'd like to make this script as clever as possible.

Comment: @Geaorge: now I have to admit that I didn't ru the code. I merely inspected it. But I do generate three different kinds of line breaks in my c code; two types need to be counted and one should not be.  Actually, I most only generated cpp lines which should be counted and other that shouldn't to avoid the problem when I "fix up" `wc`'s count. I'll run it and report back.

Comment: It isn't running for me. Firefox 3.6.13, Greesemonkey 0.9.1, everything enable, reload the page and the error console says " Error: 
Source File: file:///Users/dmckee/Library/ Application%20Support/Firefox/Profiles/ r5dicgzx.default/gm_scripts/code_golf_se_counter/code_golf_se_counter.user.js
Line: 19"

Comment: dmckee: *Looking into it...*

Comment: @George, it may be Greesemonkey's fault. I see some comments at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/ that seem to blame 0.9.1.

Comment: @dmckee: Just in case, I have pushed a new update. Also, the script will automatically check for updates now.

Comment: @George, when calculating "Note: the shortest piece of code on this page is currently XX bytes.", could you only use first code block on each answer? pls take a look [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/474/write-a-json-validator) question, if you are not sure what I mean.

Comment: We really need this to be a [built-in feature](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/43/should-character-counts-be-mandatory/45#45)

Comment: @S.Mark: I most certainly can. Look for it in the next release.

Comment: @marcog: That would be nice - if they included this with the other JS code on the page.

Comment: Ever since installing this on Chrome 10.0.648.18 dev, I haven't been able to post comments on questions.  I haven't tested it elsewhere, but disabling the script fixed the issue.

Comment: @George like Bass said, it breaks comments on Chrome, when I click to add/load more comments I get this stack trace http://tinypic.com/r/hs72pz/7 hope it helps

Comment: @Juan: Thanks! *Looking into it...*

Comment: @Bass, @Juan: The latest version now has the fix. Comments work fine now.

Comment: @George, Thanks for the update, now working as expected :-)

Comment: @dmckee: I finally verified that it works on Firefox now.

Comment: Hehe! That's cool! So [my latest entry](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/586/robot-finds-kitten/642#642) has some of the "unnecessary" line-breaks I generally use to keep the golfed version from having a horizontal scrollbar. Identifying them as necessary or unnecessary would be hard problem indeed.

Comment: @dmckee: Yes, and it would require the script to know beforehand what language it was parsing. And even then, it would have to detect which line breaks are required by syntax.

Comment: Suggestion for future versions: don't display the "current winner" banner unless the question is tagged code-golf (or otherwise filter on whatever mechanism we choose for telling golf posts from non-golf ones).

Comment: @dmckee: Hmmm... I never thought of that. I like the tag method. Should we go with that?

Comment: @George: Is the script producing the "smallest" tab I'm seeing? If so, it's doing it on my profile to, where it doesnt cause any trouble aside from confusing me.

Comment: @dmckee: Yup. I need to have it appear only for questions. But it does work for questions.

Comment: yeah the smallest tab shows up on the user/badge etc pages, but +1 this is pretty cool

Comment: @gnibbler: Thanks! I'll try to get that fixed soon.

Comment: it doesn't know dc is a language consider http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/733/calculate-the-last-digits-of-grahams-number

Comment: @gnibbler: I'll add that too in the next update. Thanks!

Comment: Doesnt count just the first code block, it will also catch the first backtick block if it is first. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby

Comment: @dmckee, @gnibbler: I have fixed that issue now.

Comment: @Bass: Yes, it is designed to do that because quite a few entries use the backtick operator for their answer.

Comment: @George: Thanks for clarifying that, though it does break up the lines in an odd way when used like it was in the first answer of that question.

Comment: @Bass: Yeah. I'll try to find a way to fix that if I can.

Comment: Would it be possible to have the script only active on questions with the "code-golf" tag? Maybe that justifies the existence of the tag too  :)

Comment: @gnibbler: Yes, that's in the works.

Comment: @George: The History says the tabs were removed for the pages that didn't use it, though it's still showing up everywhere.

Comment: @Bass: It is? Are you using the latest version? What pages is the extra tab showing up on?

Comment: @George: I updated it when I opened my browser.  Uninstalled and then reinstalled it again shortly before making the comment.  But it just prompted me to update to the newest version again.

Comment: @gnibbler: That's fixed now. It only displays for `code-golf` questions now.

Comment: @Bass: Are you using Chrome? That does sound odd.

Comment: @George: I was using Chrome dev 10.  The latest update seems to have fixed that issue though.

Comment: Could you add support for `code-bowling`? In these questions, the largest is the winner.

Comment: @Nyu: Sure. Sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: @Nyu: ...and **done!** `code-bowling` is now supported, as well as a new 'largest' sorting method for those posts.

Comment: @George: I can report that your experimental theme works on my Mac with Firefox. And, thankfully, I can report that turning it off works too. Yikes! But thanks again for the script, it's very nice.

Comment: @dmckee: Don't worry... it's completely experimental. It's a long way from being complete and still has many very large issues. Thanks for trying it though.

Comment: @George: What's the syntax for forcing the language interpretation. On [heavily golfed c it sometimes treats it as shell script](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/noughts-and-crosses-aka-tic-tac-toe/1059#1059) (all the leading '#'s I guess).

Comment: @dmckee: Actually, I just noticed that too. That's a bug. It should figure that out itself.

Comment: @dmckee: Okay, I fixed it. Just reinstall with the link in this post and it should be fixed (hopefully).

Comment: **1. A typo**: if the language is not found, the userscript says *The above [Uknown] block has n characters.*. **2.** That experimental theme is very nice, though parts of codes which aren't highlighted are in black, and these can't be seen on the black background.

Comment: @Nyu: That's actually not a typo - it's supposed to do that when it can't detect the language. As for the theme, it's still a work in progress.

Comment: @George No, it says **Uknown**, and it should be **Unknown**.

Comment: @Nyu: Oh, sorry - that's a mistake - you were right. I'll get that fixed soon.

Comment: It doesn't seem to detect [Lua](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/guess-the-number/1177#1177) and [Basic](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/guess-the-number/1114#1114)…

Comment: @Nyu: I'll add those in the next update.

Comment: @George, For those of us that can see deleted posts, they are being calculated too. They should probably be suppressed. Is it possible to have the "run" button enabled for the "code-challenge" tag too?

Comment: @gnibbler: Hmmm... It would be pretty easy to ignore deleted entries. As for adding a run option to 'code-challenge', perhaps that can be done.

Comment: @gnibbler: That's now fixed. Deleted answers should be ignored.

Comment: Thanks George, looks good.

Comment: I clicked the install link in Opera 11.50, and it just takes me to the javascript source code.

Comment: @recursive: You need to use [these instructions](http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/using/#writingscripts) to install UserScripts in Opera.

Comment: @George Edison: Thanks.  Apparently I've been living under a rock.  I never knew "user scripts" were a specific feature.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison - Great script - but could you perhaps also add support for the R language?

Comment: What do I click to display the Options menu in order to enable the theme? I can't seem to find a settings button anywhere.

Comment: @WendiKidd: It should be in the top bar to the left of your username.

Comment: Where can I download `Code Golf UserScript` from? The source link return no file. Is there somewhere a new project page?

Comment: @avall: No, that's something I need to fix. I'll add it to my list.

Comment: The userscript is unavailable from the links above.

Comment: @Xantix I noticed that too, I only just stumbled upon this script again after a few years and it would be great to be able to use it!

Comment: Chrome does have userscript manager add-ons available, I'm currently using Tampermonkey for it.

Comment: Script still unavailable.

Answer (score 5):

Please support binary hex dumps counter. an example [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/997/render-digital-clock-style-numbers/1013#1013), and copy-pasted as follows.

```
0000000: 332c 7b3a 533b 2e7b 3438 2d22 5e70 285d  3,{:S;.{48-"^p(]
0000010: 7025 d3c4 4ab1 7d4a b8dc 4469 ce41 2222  p%..J.}J..Di.A""
0000020: f303 227b 6261 7365 7d2f 3330 2f53 3d33  .."{base}/30/S=3
0000030: 2f3d 7b22 5f20 7c22 3d7d 257d 256e 407d  /={"_ |"=}%}%n@}
0000040: 2f3b                                     /;
```

My current idea is that, if the `.text()` is startswith `/^0{3,}: /` which is `0000000:` 
then do
`.text().match(/ [\da-z]{2}|[\da-z]{2}(?= )/gim).length`, which gave me 66 chars.

There is another one [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/997/render-digital-clock-style-numbers/1009#1009) with slightly different format. Should work too, but I havn't tested well that though :)

Comment: Cool. I'll certainly add that feature when I get a chance.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the userscript and the new 'Grainy' theme have a small issue. All inline code blocks are displaying as `block` making some comments with suggestions for corrections etc. really long. [Example 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3143/737), [example 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3147/737). It's not serious - nothing's actually broken - but I thought I'd let you know.

As a temporary workaround until this is officially fixed, you can edit the script source (via *Manage User Scripts...* from the Greasemonkey menu) and add the following line somewhere after the header:

```
GM_addStyle("code.prettyprint { display: inline; }");
```

Comment: Pictures on [a meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126956/2509) I should not have made.

Comment: Yeah, I found that pretty annoying too, so I came up with a workaround.  As far as I can tell, it doesn't seem to be causing any unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 3):

When you extract username, could you strip revision part?

for example, [Forecast the weather](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/404/forecast-the-weather)

```
Current winner: 21 revsJoey's [Unknown] entry has 103 characters.
```

probably, `.replace(/[^<]+<br>/,'')` will work.

Comment: Good catch. I have fixed that and will issue a new release shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with line breaks correctly is non-trivial.

Just looking at c-like languages there are at least three classes

1. The newline ending a pre-processor line. These are required and *should* count.
2. Newlines inserted only for limiting line length. They *shouldn't* count *unless...*
3. Newlines for limiting line length inserted in lieu of a space that would otherwise be required which *should* count.

And telling the last two classes apart requires lexing the preceding and subsequent "words" with and without some whitespace to know if they can be safely jammed together. And that, of course, is language specific.

Comment: I totally see what you're saying (I'm a C++ programmer myself). It would be rather difficult to check each line ending in regards to these criterion, but it would be a nice feature. It may be a far-off-down-the-road feature.

Comment: Changed my mind. This feature should be added very soon.

Comment: There is an experimental version of this available now.

Comment: @George: I'm impressed. Now I have to double check a couple of cases, because it looks like I counted them wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I have added a menu to the top of every page now:

[image]

However, the options item is not functional. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas as far as configurable settings goes:

- **What settings do you want to be able to configure?** For example, perhaps it would be nice to be able to add extra languages to the search list or to disable certain features?
- **How should these settings be stored?** Should I continue using cookies, or turn to HTML5 local storage? Any thoughts?

Comment: How about setting the shortest sorting as default? You should use one of the jQuery storage plugins, that chooses whatever storage it can take.

Comment: @Juan: jQuery storage? Hmmm... never thought of that - thanks! I'll be sure to make that an option.

Comment: @Juan: There. v0.29 now uses HTML5 storage where possible.

Comment: @Juan: With v0.32, that is now a configurable setting.

Comment: My options don't appear to have any effect (don't save?)... I've tried with Chrome 18/Win 7 and FF (most recent version, not sitting at that PC)/Win Server 2k3

Comment: @Gaffi: I'll look into it.

Comment: In fact, I know this may be a _bit_ late, but the flaw is in the checking whether the checkboxes are checked: you're checking for `.attr('checked')==true` to give your answer, but `.attr('checked')` returns `'checked'`. Not `true`. Just remove the ` == true` part and everything works completely fine! :D

Answer (score 1):

### Questions to consider:

Here are some things to be considered and discussed as this little script grows in functionality.

- **What languages do we want to skip?** Someone on the chat mentioned that there are some languages (like HQ9+) that should be skipped and not counted when determining the smallest piece of code.

  **Update:** HQ9+ is now disqualified.
- **Does the character totaling code need adjustment?** There are a few things to consider when totaling up the characters in a code snippet. Like: *Should all newlines count?*, *Should trailing and leading newlines count?*, *Indentation?*

Please comment below to voice your opinion on these issues.

Comment: Is that HQ9+ exclusion really worth it?  After all, there are only 4 (overestimated) problems it can be used in!

Comment: @JB: Yes, but there may be more of these types of entries down the road. But perhaps a better way would be to exclude items with a score of < 0. Then we can all go and vote down the HQ9+ entry. (Not sure if that's really a solution.)

Comment: For item #2, I think `\n` may matter a) depending on the language (in some languages, spaces/newlines matter - VBA for example), and b) depending on the challenge (some posters/askers specify this, some do not - perhaps if the site had more stringent guidelines?)

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: Include scores for the posts.

Anarchy Golf gives 10000 points to the shortest answer(s) and after that the score is calculated as follows:

```
minimal solution length
----------------------- ⋅ 10000
   solution length
```

So a solution twice the length of the shortest one will have 5000 points.

That way you have a rough measure how close each solution is to the currently top-rated one.

Comment: Cool... I never heard of that before.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if the code provided is valid base64, your script should detect that and display the size it would have when decoded, which is easy to calculate: remove all the whitespace, remove the trailing `=` characters, multiply the length by 3 and divide by 4 (round down).

To give an example where it makes sense to post a base64-encoded answer, see [my Perl script that uses unprintable bytes in the source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/985/koch-snowflake-codegolf/1749#1749).

Answer (score 0):

On this question,

[Physics golf: inclined shooting.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/901/physics-golf-inclined-shooting)

```
Current winner: George EdisonFUZxxl's Haskell
```

You may use, `.find('.user-details a:last').text()`, since author is on the right most

Comment: Ah. Thank you for finding that. I forget that `.text()` combines the text from all matched elements. I'll get that fixed soon.

Comment: There. I just released a fix for that - thanks!

Comment: @George, Thanks. this one works, but [other](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/404/forecast-the-weather) one still having issue for `.replace(/[^<]+<br>/,'')` may be you need to use `.html` instead of `.text` to strip first part of `<br>`?

Comment: or you may try `.replace(/[^\n]+\n/,'')` instead of `<br>` with .text()?

Comment: @SMark: The one you're linking to is working fine with the latest release... are you using 0.27?

Comment: @George, really, I am seeing `21 revsJoey's [Unknown]` in chrome win32, I just uninstalled and reinstalled it, still same, I guess `.text()` stripped `<br>` tag / or converted to `\n`

Comment: same on firefox 3.6.12 win32 greasemonkey 0.9.0 too.

Comment: @SMark: Well to be honest, I'm using `.replace(/^\d+ revs/,'')` because `.text()` strips the HTML out.

Comment: @SMark: Can you open the Chrome console when you're on that page and type: `$('#answer-443 .user-details:last a:last').text().replace(/^\d+ revs/,'')`

Comment: @George, Sorry You might be right, I am having issue with my cache. I could see `Joey` with your code in my chrome console

Comment: @George, now looks good now. thank you. when your script try to autoupdate, could you add url with version numbers like `....user.js?0.27` or something else like random numbers? autoupdate script looks failed because of the cache.

Comment: @SMark: Hmmm... I never thought of that. That's a good idea. I'll see about implementing that.

Comment: @SMark: There. The update code on my server will supply unique URLs from now on. Hopefully this will not happen again.

Comment: Thanks @George, that would be nice too.

Comment: @SMark: You can try it out by triggering an update check. Simply delete the `codegolf_lastcheck` cookie and visit the home page.

Comment: I got 0.28 working now @George. Thanks