# auto count the number of chars in the code section

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, characters

will there be for each answer an auto calculation for the "code" section that was marked up by the user

```
like this is a marked up code section
```

and write here total characters : 37 as an auto feature for this special form?

Answer (score 5):

George Edison, [has provided a UserScript to do just that](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/170/78).