# Can we find a way to automatically execute people's code?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

This site gets a relatively small number of posts.  Could we contact IDEOne or somebody, and get a script going to test people's code automatically?  Maybe put up a "powered by" logo somewhere?

Comment: Lots of places to try for setting this up can be found in [Where to find a working Foo environment for testing answers?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/202/where-to-find-a-working-foo-environment-for-testing-answers). Not sure where George's script is going right now.

Comment: I think the main problem would be providing stdin or whatever to run the testcases. If you can solve that, I think it's a great idea

Comment: @gnibbler, ideone solves that. Unfortunately they don't support GolfScript, because it isn't a RH rpm.

Comment: @Peter: GolfScript is just a Ruby-based interpreter (golfscript.rb), so you can probably include it as part of your ideone submission. (Not tested.)

Comment: @Chris, it must be possible to create a script to take a GS program and the GS interpreter and munge them together into a single Ruby program, but ugh.

Answer (score 2):

[George Edison's](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/362/george-edison) [User script](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/170/737) provides the ability to run some code (using Codepad, I think).

Answer (score 0):

IDEONE expects some boilerplate for scala for example, naming conventions and a main-method, and a specific scala version. Enforcing compatibility would need to take this into account. I'm pretty sure, for other languages the situation is similar, isn't it? C, C++, Java, C#?

Maybe it isn't that restricted for scripting languages like ruby, python, perl, ... ?