# Is the Chrome UserScript still recommended?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, code-golf

If I recall correctly, the [chrome user script](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170/code-golf-userscript-to-help-in-navigating-the-site-v0-37-now-available) used to be recommended in the About/FAQ pages somewhere, but I can't find it anymore.

I know that UserScripts must be installed from the Chrome Web Store now, is this why it has been removed?

Are there plans to migrate the script into an extension that can be installed from the web store?  I found it very useful when I had it a few months back and it would help [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) submissions that are posted a little slower.

Comment: I don't know anything about chrome. The script works (or at least worked) in (at least) Firefox and Opera, too.

Comment: @dmckee When you try to install it, chrome prevents it because it isn't in the web store anymore.  I'll look for a workaround, but it would be nice if there was just an extension.

Comment: There's nothing better, so I'd say it's still recommended. However they seem to have made it _very difficult_ to install any script into chrome that's not from the store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This procedure seems to be a workaround

Download the script from [here](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/codegolf/count_it.user.js) (Save Link As...)

Now visit this url chrome://chrome/extensions/

Drag the script from Downloads and drop in the window.