# Userscript for showing character count

Tags: discussion

*(this is basically just a simplified version of [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/170/3808))*

I have created a simple userscript that shows a small tab above every code block that tells you its character count. I posted it on Stack Apps, but I thought I would also post it here so people from codegolf.SE will see it.
https://stackapps.com/q/4342/17430

Example:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Er...was the code from http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170/code-golf-userscript-to-help-in-navigating-the-site-v0-37-now-available?rq=1 not working, or does your do something better or different? Not that having two choices is a bad thing or anything.

Comment: @dmckee No, it's just a simplified version. This one's very small (less than 400 bytes) and simple.

Comment: @dmckee One advantage I can see for this is that it seems to show the character count of every code block rather than just the first in every answer.

Comment: It would be best practice to not trash any previous `window.onload`. And it would be nice for userscript novices such as myself to see a comment explaining why you go through the rigmarole of injecting a string to be `eval`ed.

Comment: Also, check out http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12324/194 . Pretty-printing causes problems.

Comment: @Peter I fixed the pretty printing issue by using `$(this).text()`. I'll add an explanation once I have access to a computer