# New user script to sort answers by length

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, user-interface

Since the new Stack Exchange top bar apparently broke the [old user script](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170/code-golf-userscript-to-help-in-navigating-the-site-v0-37-now-available), I wrote a [quick and dirty replacement for it](https://stackapps.com/questions/4570/code-golf-se-answer-sorter).

The *only* thing my new user script does is what I felt was the most important function of the old one: it adds a new tab to the answer list that can be used to **sort answers by length** of the first code block:

[image: Screenshot of new "shortest" answer tab]

It does *not* include any of the other fancy features of the old user script, but I think it's a *lot* better than nothing.

The user script has been tested in Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome.  To install it, first download and install the [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (for Firefox) or [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) (for Chrome) extension, and then click the "install / download" button below:

> ## [<kbd>Install / Download</kbd>](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/9b55e1f96ee129d53466/raw/267df3d186d00e9ae874ff911e5f20ed6078529d/codegolf_sorter.user.js)
>
> <sup>[view source](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/9b55e1f96ee129d53466) / [StackApps post](https://stackapps.com/questions/4570/code-golf-se-answer-sorter)</sup>

The script may also work in other browsers with compatible user script support, such as Safari or Opera.  [See here for instructions on installing user scripts on different browsers.](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info)

**Edit:** Since version 0.3, the script should also work if installed directly as a Chrome extension using the alternative instructions above.

**Edit 2:** ...and v0.4 should solve issues with direct links to answers.  (Previously, re-sorting the answers could leave a completely different answer in view than the one you wanted; now, the view should automatically jump back to the target answer.)

---

Ps. Shameless plug: if you like this user script, you may also want to try the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch), another user script I've written to fix various neglected bugs and inconveniences in the Stack Exchange user interface.

Comment: Pps. Also tagging this as [tag:feature-request], because it would be _really awesome_ to have this feature built into the Stack Exchange software running this site. We can always hope...

Comment: Ooh, this exists? I had no idea; thanks! Another useful userscript that I use is [this one](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/178565) for showing the length of code blocks.

Comment: @FireFly Yay, that's [the one I made](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/670/3808) :P I didn't know anyone else used it.

Comment: I like it, but [for my question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12760/9275), it shows a 18 char Perl solution **before** a 17 char Golfscript solution. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @ProgramFOX: ...because the Perl solution is actually also 17 chars?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Thanks! I actually thought that the userscript would look at the character count included in the header of the answer.

Comment: I like this. I like this a lot.

Comment: You should make a "longest" section, too.

Comment: I am marking this as [meta-tag:status-deferred] because implementing this into the system itself will require a lot of dev work for something mostly specific to our site, but I don't want to make this [meta-tag:status-declined] myself yet.