# Sort by code size for code-golf problems

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, code-golf

For easier position calculation and as a handy way for the questioner, a sort by code size feature should be added which would sort out all the answers from the very least byte-ed to the most byte-ed.

Comment: I don't think this is likely to happen, as I think it would affect all sites. Questions could implement something like [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2492/31625) though. (Remember to thank @Optimizer!)

Comment: I don't think this would work well as an actual feature of the site, because it would require a reliable way to figure out the size in the first place. If the sorting parses that from the answer, then there would certainly be a way to cheat the parser. So just using a Stack Snippet seems best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think the team is going to implement this because it would only be useful here. However, there is a [user script](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/900/9275) written by [Ilmari Karonen](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3191/ilmari-karonen). that adds a "shortest" tab to questions which sorts answers by code length. The script is a new version of [this user script](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/170/9275) written by [Nathan Osman](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/362/nathan-osman), because that script didn't work anymore after some design changes on Stack Exchange.